# Simple object pool template container in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, stl

The main advantage of this pattern is when I often create and destroy objects, which in this case are often used.

I made this because I needed to track several short timers at the same time, but it can also  be used for stuff like missiles or else.

```
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

#define itv(TYPE) std::vector<TYPE>::iterator

using namespace std;
template <class TYPE>
struct object_pool
{
    std::vector<TYPE> pool;
    std::queue<size_t> avail;
    TYPE & operator[](const size_t & i) { return pool[i]; }
    void add(size_t & pos)
    {
        if(avail.empty()) // no reusable object
        { pool.push_back(TYPE()); pos = pool.size()-1; }
        else
        { pos = avail.back(); avail.pop(); }
    }
    void rem(size_t & a) { avail.push(a); }
    size_t size() { return pool.size(); }
};
```

What do you think ?

Answer (score 7):

Don't do this:

```
using namespace std;
```

In anything other than a toy this will cause problems.

I don't like this:

```
#define itv(TYPE) std::vector<TYPE>::iterator
```

With C++11 this type if thing has been resolved by `auto`.

I would also define the iterator in terms of the object pool:

```
template <class TYPE>
struct object_pool
{
    typedef std::vector<TYPE>::iterator  iterator;
```

I would hide the fact that internally the `object_pool` uses a vector and queue. I would then add the obligatory functions to extract information:

```
template <class TYPE>
class object_pool
{
    std::vector<TYPE> pool;
    std::queue<size_t> avail;

  public:
    typedef std::vector<TYPE>::iterator       iterator;
    typedef std::vector<TYPE>::const_iterator const_iterator;

    iterator       begin()       { return pool.begin();}
    iterator       end()         { return pool.end();}
    const_iterator begin() const { return pool.begin();}
    const_iterator end()   const { return pool.end();}
```

To access elements I would also provide const version

```
    TYPE&       operator[](std::size_t index)       { return pool[index];}
    TYPE&       at(std::size_t index)               { return pool.at(index);}

    TYPE const& operator[](std::size_t index) const { return pool[index];}
    TYPE const& at(std::size_t index) const         { return pool.at(index);}
```

The methods that can be const should be const:

```
    size_t size() const { return pool.size(); }
             //  ^^^^^^^
```

The implementation details are fine.

```
    void add(size_t & pos)
    {
        if(avail.empty()) // no reusable object
        { pool.push_back(TYPE()); pos = pool.size()-1; }
        else
        { pos = avail.back(); avail.pop(); }
    }
    void rem(size_t & a) { avail.push(a); }
```

I would change the add() so it returned pos:

```
    size_t add();
```

Also the vector starts off very small and re-sizes to get bigger.
To make sure that it does not re-size too often I would add a constructor that gives the vector a reasonable size to start with:

```
object_pool::object_pool()
{
    pool.reserve(1000);
}
```

But I think you are using the wrong technique.
I would use a pool allocator and plug it into the vector.

You can read more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2984434/14065

Comment: boost seems like a little complicated for what I want to do with do with it.

Comment: You don't need to use boost. But implementing an allocator would seem a better solution (and also quicker). Though it adds some extra complexity you probably don't need. You need to way complexity against the added advantage for your particular situation. Note: by learning how to use allocators makes your use of the STL more effective.